# how to make a global variable in jquery loop

Tags: jquery

I want to make  all the keys as variables and want to use outside $.each,instead of using data.company_id, want it to be used as company_id

```
success     : function(data){
             console.log(data);

             $.each(data,function(key,val){
key = val;
                 })
console.log(company_id);
```

Comment: Elaborate your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
success : function(data){
$(data).each(function(){
console.log(this.company_id)
})
}
```

try somethingb like this

Comment: basically it should be like extract function in php , which convert array into varialbe

Comment: this should work then since you are iterating each element

Answer (score -1):

```
var check = 0
```

place variable on the top of the jquery.

Comment: Can you please clarify how this answers the question?

Comment: place the variable above your jquery loop and define its value and you can use anywhere in the loop so it is called global variable which is used every where in its scope